# Android: Spinner dropdown arrow goes out of the box

Tags: spinner, android

I'm trying to use a spinner view element in my android application, but the dropdown arrow always goes out of the element box.

**Code from layout file:**

```
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

**And Here is the cropped output:**

[image: SPINNER DROPDOWN ARROW UI BREAK]

Answer (score 0):

I dont use any mode.
May be that is the problem.
[image]

Comment: If you are using custom backgroung then use margin for arrow

Comment: I tried with not setting any mode too.. but it doesn't work. If I change the theme to Holo.Light.Spinner, it looks fine like above in Preview layout, but when I run it on Lollipop emulator it breaks. :(

Comment: I have not tried lollipop yet. I am still working with  Kitkat